# success or failure of transaction function in android room kotlin

Tags: kotlin, transactions, android-room, dao

i want to update two tables at a time and want a response ( success or failure )

Dao :

```
@Transaction
suspend fun updateVariantValues(id: Int, is_Notify:Boolean, cart_count: String, product_id: Int)  {
    updateVariantTable(id,is_Notify,cart_count,product_id)
    updateCartTable(id,cart_count)
}

@Query("UPDATE Variants SET cart_count= :cart_count, is_notify_me= :is_Notify,product_id= :product_id WHERE id = :id")
fun updateVariantTable(id: Int, is_Notify:Boolean, cart_count: String?, product_id: Int) : Int

@Query("UPDATE CartList SET qty= :qty WHERE id = :id")
fun updateCartTable(id: Int, qty: String) : Int
```

how do i know if this two tables updated successfully or not

viewmodel :

```
fun updateVariantTableinRoom(id:Int, cart_count:String, is_notify:Boolean, product_id:Int) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

  productsDao.updateVariantValues(id, is_notify, cart_count,product_id)
     
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming success/failure is whether an update was made or not (see below in regard to ambiguities) then change the two update functions called by `updateVariantValues` to return an `Int`

- e.g. `@ Update fun updateVariantTable(....): Int`

The value returned will be the number of rows that were updated ()

You can then modify the `updateVariantTable` function to behave as you wish according to whether or not 0 or greater then 0 is returned by the functions inside. e.g. you could have:-

```
@Transaction
suspend fun updateVariantValues(id: Int, is_Notify:Boolean, cart_count: String, product_id: Int): Int  {
    /* returns 0 if Variant was not updated */
    /* returns 1 if Variant was updated but Cart was not */
    /* returns 3 if both updated */
    var result = 0
    if (updateVariantTable(id,is_Notify,cart_count,product_id) > 0) {
        result += 1
        if (updateCartTable(id, cart_count) > 0) {
            result += 2
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

The actual question is a little ambiguous in regards to success or failure as,

- some failures will result in an exception (such as Foreign Key constraints)

  - from the linked documentation *The ON CONFLICT algorithm does not apply to FOREIGN KEY constraints.*
- others will depend upon the onConflictStrategy if using the `@Update`, whilst if updating via an `@Query` then it depends upon the use of `UPDATE OR ???????`  e.g. as per:-

[image]

- see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html for further information for SQlite's `On CONFLICT` clause.

Comment: i have updated my question ..please tell me with code how to retrieve the success result in viewmodel @MikeT

Comment: this did not work @MikeT